# Ошибки типов в Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
loadMtx :: String -> IO [[Double]] -- парсер
loadMtx text = do
    delete [] (map (map(read)) ((map (delete "") (map (map (strip)) (map (Data.List.Split.splitOn " ") (splitOn ";" text))))))

main = do
    text <- readFile "matrix.txt"
    mtx <- loadMtx text
    putStrLn $ show $ mtx
```

Выдаёт:

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO [Double]'
            with actual type `[[a0]]'
In the return type of a call of `delete'
```

Вообще, не до конца понял IO (), но потребность в сохранении готовой матрицы есть, так как не хочется каждый раз файл перечитывать. Как это сделать?

Comment: Что мешает сделать:

    loadMtx :: String -> [[Double]]
    loadMtx text = delete ...
    ....
    main = do
        ...
        putStrLn $ show $ mtx where mtx = loadMtx text

Comment: main.hs:20:31: Not in scope: `text'

Comment: Как писал @Андрей, нафига у loadMtx тип IO [[Double]]? (Кстати, в сообщении об ошибке тип вообще IO [Double]. Но уж если надо монаду, то есть функция 

     return :: Monad m => a -> m a

т.е.

     return $ delete [] (map ...

Comment: Мне не обязательно использовать IO, просто иначе я не понимаю, как присвоить значение внутри main (как организовать код, например?), чтобы каждый раз не перечитывать файл для генерации матрицы.

Comment: Утверждение: `IO` имеет отношение только к работе с файлом. Все остальное можно либо подставить в код, либо вынести с помощью конструкций `let ... in` и `where ...`.

Comment: @имя слишком коротко

     чтобы каждый раз не перечитывать файл для генерации матрицы.

Это Вы об чём? Haskell -- не Це и не джава. И даже не php. Он ленивый

@Андрей ну файлом-не файлом. С внешним миром

Answer (score 1):

Предполагая, что `matrix.txt` выглядит, например, так

```
1.0 2.0 3.0; 4.0 5.0 6.0    ;
7.0
8.0
9.0
```

можно использовать следующий код:

```
import Data.List
import Data.List.Split

parseMtx :: String -> [[Double]]
parseMtx text = map (map read) $ delete [] $ map words $ splitOn ";" text

main :: IO ()
main = do
    text <- readFile "matrix.txt"
    let mtx = parseMtx text
    print mtx
```

Функция [`words`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-String.html#v:words) разделяет строку на "слова", поедая все пробелы между ними.

Если в дальше по коду пользоваться `mtx`, то файл перечитываться не будет и матрица будет строиться только один раз.

В качестве упражнения можно переписать `parseMtx` в бесточечной нотации:

```
parseMtx :: String -> [[Double]]
parseMtx = map (map read) . delete[] . map words . splitOn ";"
```